# drag and drop using selenium on a webpage built on Angular2

Tags: c#, selenium, angular, drag-and-drop, automated-tests

I am currently trying to implement drag and drop on a webpage built in angular2. I am using Selenium webdriver to do that.
I have tried all the methods suggested including the Actions library to drag and drop which is native to selenium.

```
    Actions builder = new Actions(driver);

    Action dragAndDrop = builder.clickAndHold(src).moveToElement(trgt).release(trgt).build();

    dragAndDrop.perform();
```

When I run the test, I can see that the element is clicked on, but the moveToElement() and release() do not do anything.
I read some posts about using javascript to do the drag and drop, but before trying it out I wanted to check if there is any other solution out there.

Comment: I'd love to know the answer to this as well, OP if you've found anything I'd be greatly interested.

Comment: Hi Cromzinc, we had to resort to JQuery for this (which was suggested online elsewhere). If you want more information I would be more than happy to help.